# Procedure is giving error when table dont have any row

Tags: mysql

I have below database table : Table name - dim_module

```
id       Creation_Date         Goals  Alternative    Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G1         A         0.86
2   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G1         B         0.87
3   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G2         A         0.5
4   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G2         B         0
```

I am using below procedure for getting desired output

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `stmt`()
BEGIN
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(goals = ''',
      goals,
      ''', round(value, 2), NULL)) AS ',
      goals
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM sgwebdb.dim_module;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT alternative, ', @sql, ' FROM sgwebdb.dim_module GROUP BY alternative');

prepare stmt from @sql;
```

But if Dim_Module don't have any row then procedure is not take care and I am getting error.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Please help to take care of empty table.

Comment: Would you expect any meaningful result if Dim_Module doesn't have any rows?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because `@sql` is null.

Try setting it to some value with IFNULL

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT alternative, ', IFNULL(@sql,'somecolumnor*here'), ' FROM sgwebdb.dim_module GROUP BY alternative');
```

Or detect that `@sql` is null and do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You may check @sql before using it within your second `SELECT`:

```
IF @sql
THEN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT alternative, ', @sql, ' FROM sgwebdb.dim_module GROUP BY alternative');
    prepare stmt from @sql;
END IF;
```